# Python 3.11 - Remove digit code runs and works but results in error

Tags: python, string, hosts

I created simple code to remove digits from hosts file.

```
with open(r'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts', 'r') as infile, open(r'C:\XXXX\XXX\X.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for i in infile:
        if not i[0].isdigit():
            print("Line Skipped")
        else:
            if int(i[0]) == 0:
                B = i[8:]
                outfile.write(B)
            elif int(i[0]) == 1:
                B = i[10:]
                outfile.write(B)
```

The script runs fine, until, it returns an error.
I've examined the hosts file where it broke and the data is not at fault.

The error returned is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "<pyshell#142>", line 2, in <module><br>
    for i in infile:<br>
  File "C:\XXX\Python\Python311\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]<br>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4244: character maps to undefined
```

I understand its pointing to a library, is it to do with running memory? 
Should I be running the script differently?

 Im running this code from inside the python IDLE shell

Comment: This looks like a encoding problem try adding `encoding="utf8"` when you open the file, or if you know what encoding it is in add that

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Yeah that's what I assumed was wrong based on some research. Il try this on the next run. 
If it is encoding, how come it ran for a couple of thousand entries?

Comment: Searching the [python] tag for "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d " returns 73 results.  I suggest you look through them.

Comment: @ChristAHFER there are similarities between the encodings. you program recognized all chars the first couple of thousand entries then it found one it did not know what to do with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding issue related to the open() function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).